# pandas - create new columns based on existing columns / conditional average

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am new to Pandas and I am trying to learn column creation based on conditions applied to already existing columns. I am working with cellular data and this is how my source data looks like (the 2 columns to the right are empty to begin with):

```
DEVICE_ID |   MONTH   | TYPE    | DAY    | COUNT  | LAST_MONTH| SEASONAL_AVG
8129      | 201601    | VOICE   | 1      | 8      |           |      
8129      | 201502    | VOICE   | 1      | 5      |           |        
8129      | 201501    | VOICE   | 1      | 2      |           |        
8321      | 201403    | DATA    | 3      | 1      |           |            
2908      | 201302    | TEXT    | 5      | 4      |           |            
8129      | 201406    | VOICE   | 2      | 3      |           |            
8129      | 201306    | VOICE   | 2      | 7      |           |            
3096      | 201501    | DATA    | 5      | 6      |           |            
8129      | 201301    | VOICE   | 1      | 2      |           |
```

I created a dataframe with this data and named it df.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DEVICE_ID'  : [8129, 8129,8129,8321,2908,8129,8129,3096,8129], 
                   'MONTH'      : [201601,201502,201501,201403,201302,201406,201306,201501,201301],
                   'TYPE'       : ['VOICE','VOICE','VOICE','DATA','TEXT','VOICE','VOICE','DATA','VOICE'],
                   'DAY'        : [1,1,1,3,5,2,2,5,1],
                   'COUNT'      : [8,5,2,1,4,3,7,6,2]
                   })
```

I am trying to create two additional columns to df: 'LAST_MONTH' and 'SEASONAL_AVG'. Logic for these two columns:

- LAST_MONTH: for the corresponding DEVICE_ID & TYPE & DAY combination return the previous month's COUNT. Ex: For row 1 (DEVICE_ID: 8129, TYPE: VOICE, DAY: 1,  MONTH 201502), LAST_MONTH will be COUNT from row 2 (DEVICE_ID: 8129, TYPE: VOICE, DAY: 1,  MONTH 201501. If there is no record for the previous month, LAST_MONTH will be zero.
- SEASONAL_AVG: for the corresponding DEVICE_ID & TYPE & DAY combination return the average of corresponding month from all previous years (data starts from 201301). Ex: SEASONAL_AVG for row 0 = average of COUNTs of rows 2 and 8. There will always be at least one record for corresponding month from the past. Need not be for for all TYPEs and DAYs combinations, but at least some of the possible combinations will be present for all DEVICE_IDs.

Your help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT1:

```
def last_month(record):

    year  = int(str(record['MONTH'])[:4])
    month = int(str(record['MONTH'])[-2:])

    if month in (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10):
        x = str(0)+str(month-1)
        y = int(str(year)+str(x))
        last_month = int(y)
    elif month == 1:
        last_month = int(str(year-1)+str(12))
    else:
        last_month = int(str(year)+str(month-1))

    day = record['DAY']
    cellular_type = record['TYPE']
    #return record['COUNT']
    return record['COUNT'][(record['MONTH'] == last_month) & (record['DAY'] == day) & (record['TYPE'] == cellular_type)]

df['last_month'] = df.apply (lambda record: last_month(record),axis=1)
```

Comment: Have you done anything besides create your dataframe? You need to provide a [mcve] so we know what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your comment  Wayne Werner. I was able to calculate count aggregates at monthly level, but I am trying to do that DEVICE_ID level. The data contains approx. 1.5M DEVICE_IDs (approx. 4B records), so looping if for every DEVICE_ID was proving to be very inefficient. I tried creating a function that returns LAST_MONTH data, but I get errors. I have a feeling I am not interpreting the functionality of pandas correctly.

Comment: I apologize for not being able to edit/comment nicely as others have done. I am new to this site.

Comment: @ayhan - thanks a bunch!

Comment: @data_bender: I edited your table so it can be copied and directly pasted into a dataframe using `pd.read_clipboard()`. This is the best way for people to quickly can easily test your code with your data.

Comment: @Khris - thanks for the edits and helpful pointers.